# Calculating mean anual precipitation on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using GEE to calculate mean anual precipitation between 2000 and 2019 using 
GPM: Global Precipitation Measurement (GPM) V6. Because there are 20 years in the series, I first summarize all 20 years in a new image collection "ee.ImageCollection(precip_mensual)" which contains mean precipitation for all 20 Januaries, all 20 Februaries, and so on (steps 1 & 2). 
In the resulting collection, each pixel has 12 values (one for each month). Then, next I need to somehow summarize that into an average year (step 3).

Using the "Inspector", I am not getting the values I am supposed to in points for which I know the mean value for anual precipitation. That being said, I think that either think my approach is not the correct one, or it is but there is something missing in my script.

**1) Add shapefile of study area M (using asset)**

```
Map.addLayer(M,{},'M');

var GPM = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06')
          .filter(ee.Filter.date("2000-06-01", "2019-06-30"))
          .select('precipitationCal');
```

**2) Inter-anual aggregation**
Here, I use a function to derive the average year at a monthly scale.

```
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var precip_mensual = months.map(function(m) { 
var precip_men = GPM.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).mean();
return precip_men;
});

var precip_mensual = ee.ImageCollection(precip_mensual);
print('Precipitacion', precip_mensual)
```

**3) Intra-anual aggregation**

```
var precip_mean = precip_mensual.mean().rename('precip-med').clip(M)
Map.addLayer(precip_mean, {}, 'Precipitation-Mean')

Map.centerObject(M, 4)
```

**4) Create region**

```
var ExportArea  
=ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-77.9881000000000029, -55.9185000000000016, 
-37.4998999999999967, 2.0680000000000001]);
Map.addLayer(ExportArea, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'poly');

Export.image.toDrive({
image: precip_mean, 
description:'Precipitation_mean',
folder:'WildBoar',
crs:'EPSG:4326', 
maxPixels: 1e13, 
scale:1000, 
region:ExportArea,});
```

Comment: Sorry for a very delayed response - we are trying to address all unanswered questions.

Can you give an example of an expected value and how it differs from values in EE?